# file not upload in dynamic directory in php

Tags: php, mysqli

i am upload multiple files in dynamic directory but showing error.

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(1/1533889764_Koala.jpg): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\peacock\contact.php on line 48
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\xampp\tmp\php853E.tmp' to '1/1533889764_Koala.jpg' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\peacock\contact.php on line 48

my html code :

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Attach Files : <input type="file" name="cnt_img[]" multiple="multiple"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

php code :

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {

$insert_id  = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    if ($_FILES['cnt_img']['name']!='') 

            $filefolder = mkdir($insert_id , 0777, true);


    {
        if(count($_FILES['cnt_img']['name']) > 0)
        {
            for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['cnt_img']['name']); $i++)
            {
                $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['cnt_img']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    if($tmpFilePath != "")
                    {
                        $shortname = $_FILES['cnt_img']['name'][$i];
                        $filePath = $filefolder."/".time().'_'.$_FILES['cnt_img']['name'][$i];

                        if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) 
                        {
                            $files[] = $shortname;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: try to remove the `[]` after `cnt_img` in the HTML

Comment: `$insert_id  = mysqli_insert_id($conn);` What is this line doing? I see no previous INSERT SQL

Comment: This line ?? `$filefolder = mkdir($insert_id , 0777, true);` appears to be after an IF but before the opening `{` ???

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: error not showing but files are not upload

Comment: Errors are showing. **You showed them to us**

Comment: Start by moving this line `$filefolder = mkdir($insert_id , 0777, true);` Inside the if block i.e. after the `{` not Before

Comment: anybody can help me

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes sir i fixed it but error still showing

Comment: @RiggsFolly 
$ins = $conn->prepare("insert into contacts(name,email,phone,comments)values(?,?,?,?)");
 $ins->bind_param("ssss",$name,$email,$phone,$question);
 $ins->execute();

    $insert_id  = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
     if ($_FILES['cnt_img']['name']!='') 

    {

        mkdir('contactus/'.$insert_id , 0777, true);

        if(count($_FILES['cnt_img']['name']) > 0)
        {
            for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['cnt_img']['name']); $i++)
            {

                $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['cnt_img']['tmp_name'][$i];


                    if($tmpFilePath != "")
                    {
                        $shortname = $_FILES['cnt_img']['name'][$i];
                        $filePath = "contactus/".$insert_id."/".time().'_'.$_FILES['cnt_img']['name'][$i];

                        if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) 
                        {
                            $files[] = $shortname;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }



    }
```